# jQuery Inner Submit Function Does Not Work

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, onchange

I have a problem with this jQuery code. It doesn't work as expected:

```
$('#select_dropdown').change ( function(){
    $('#form_to_submit').submit( function(event){
        $.post("process.php", { name: "John" },
    function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
    });
});
```

However, this works:

```
$('#select_dropdown').change ( function(){
    $('#form_to_submit').submit();
});
```

I wonder why the internal function on submit doesn't work.
When a user selects a value from a dropdown, the form must be submitted. The second set of codes
work but if I add an inner function to submit, it doesn't.

Basically, I want to do some ajax call after the user select on the dropdown.

Comment: Question is duplicated with this other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079546/jquery-submit-function-does-not-work-inner-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code is creating an event handler for submit event on selector $('#list_count') most likely a form element. The second code is calling the submit method on that element. The first one would be triggered when you submit the form using any method but it itself would not submit the form. What are you trying to do?

**EDIT**

Do you want to do this

```
$('#select_dropdown').change ( function(){
    $.post("process.php", { name: "John" }, function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I modified my question and added the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
$("#form_to_submit").submit(function(){
   //do your post stuff here
});

$('#select_dropdown').change ( function(){
   $("#form_to_submit").submit()
});
```

What I am doing is:

1. Define the handler for submit event of `form_to_submit`
2. Define the hander when user do the selection on `select_dropdown`, which invokes an submit even on the form.

=================

if you have the code

```
$('#list_per_page').change ( function(){
    $('#list_count').submit( function(event){
        alert('It Works!');
    });
});
```

and

```
   $('#list_count').submit();
```

then it will work. Reason being that for the "It Works" to appear, you need to trigger a submit event.

The first block is adding a handler to the submit event when the change event happens. So when `#list_per_page` changes, a submit event handler will be added to `#list_count` element.

The second block is just firing a submit even on #list_count; therefore, invoking the handler you added in the fist block.

Keep in mind that the evens happen asynchronously, it seems like you are expecting your code to run sequentially.

My code above is NOT a solution to you're problem; it is for demonstration purpose only. Please tell us what you want to achieve then people can suggest some best practices to help you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I modified my question and added the complete code.